# How to keep leading zero in a timetable

Tags: javascript, timetable, leading-zero

I've got a selection of times, but I want to keep the leading zero:

```
var fastTrainReading = [0943, 0957, 1006, 1013 , 1027, 1036, 1043, 1057, 1106, 1113, 1127, 1136, 1213, 1227, 1236, 1243, 1257, 1306, 1313, 1327, 1336, 1343, 1357, 1406, 1413, 1427, 1436, 1443, 1457, 1506, 1513, 1527, 1537, 1543, 1559, 1606, 1613, 1627, 1636, 1643, 1657, 1704, 1718, 1728, 1735, 1749, 1758, 1816, 1830, 1847, 1859, 1906, 1911, 1930, 1936, 1941, 1959, 2006, 2017, 2027];
```

This is the math performed:

```
var currentTime = hour*100 + mins;
if ((day == 0) || (day == 6)) {
    document.write ("There are no buses today");
}  else {

var displayCount = 0;
        var TrainStr1 = "";
        for (var i=0, len=fastTrainReading.length; i<len; ++i) {
            if ((fastTrainReading[i] > currentTime) && (displayCount < 2)) {
                displayCount = displayCount+1;
                TrainStr1=TrainStr1 + fastTrainReading[i] + "<br/>";
            }
        }
    }
document.write (TrainStr1)
```

I had a pretty good search through, if I missed something feel free to abuse me (but point me in the right direction).

Comment: Force the variables type to string: `TrainStr = "" + 0975;`

Comment: Actually, I think the leading zero indicates that a raw number is in Octal, but 0943 is not valid octal. The array should store plain integers (`943`) or strings (`'0943'`).

Comment: good point james.  I just read them as strings because of the leading 0.  The 0943 and 0957 is the only broken one in his set though.  I'd normalize on strings for his specific question though.

Comment: I think, the input list shouldn't contain leading zeros because that's part of the display, not the logic. Add the leading zero @ TrainStr1 += paddingFunction(fastTrainReading[i]) + "<br/>";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest solution is to store your time data as strings e.g. `var fastTrainReading = ['0943', ...`. JavaScript will cast to integer for you in your calculation routines.

For a comprehensive string formatting solution that adheres to conventional principles, try sprintf() for javascript: http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/javascript-sprintf

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `.toString()` 
like: 
`TrainStr1=TrainStr1 +`**`fastTrainReading[i].toString()`**`+ "<br/>";` 
alt to save your times as strings.

Comment: This will not work. fastTrainReading is stored as String array by default

Comment: Not true. See what the result is when you try: `alert(typeof(fastTrainReading[0]));`

Comment: @Lucky Murari: That make no sense.

Comment: I can't help Javascript working that way :( Check here that [yours will not work](http://jsfiddle.net/luckymurari/4PZSj/1/)

Answer (score 1):

By default you won't get the leading zeroes.

As you know the length of TrainStr1 is 4, you can use the following function to get zeroes.

```
function formatted(time) {
    var s = "0000" + time;
    return s.substr(s.length-4); }
```

You can call the function 'formatted' before using document.write

Answer (score 0):

You need to zero pad your numbers.

```
Number.prototype.zf = function _zeroFormat(digits)
{
    var n = this.toString(), pLen = digits - n.length;
    for ( var i = 0; i < pLen; i++)
    {
        n = '0' + n;
    }
    return n;
}

if ((fastTrainReading[i] > currentTime.zf(4)) && (displayCount < 2)) {
   displayCount = displayCount+1;
   TrainStr1=TrainStr1 + fastTrainReading[i] + "<br/>";
}
```

Once you've normalized all of your numbers to be 0-padded to 4 digits, string comparison is possible.  Otherwise, you'll have issues.  As things stand, it looks like your code was trying to compare a string (like an element from fastTrainReading) and a number (currentTime).

Answer (score 0):

Just declare your array as strings:

```
var fastTrainReading = ['0943', '0957', '1006', '1013'];
```

And don't worry `fastTrainReading[i] > currentTime` will still work.
`'100' > 99 == true`